# Matching PA system

Tags: amplifiers

Hope someone could help. not sure if this is the right place, but I'l give it a go.
I'm trying to figure out if my amp will be suitable for my speakers or its going to fry them up haha.

**amp**: `PV-2600` delivering `900w` && `4om` per channel.

**speakers**: `150w` `4-8 om's` (that's is what listed on them)

Cheers to all,

Comment: @skinny peacock Cheers for the great answer appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is the amp can easily burn up the voice coils in your speakers unless you either multiply the number of speakers power handling capabilities (more speakers) to equal the power output of the amp, or operate the amp at lower power output to match the power capabilities of your speakers. The key is to know the limitations of the system as a unit and operate it within those limitations. In this instance, it seems the speakers are the limiting factor, at least until you can obtain enough of them to handle the full output of that amplifier. You may reduce the output of the amp by wiring your speakers in series to present the amp with a higher impedance load and also just use the volume control to keep within the capabilities of the system. A safety precaution for those speakers is to always keep your volume controls turned completely down when turning the system on or off. This will prevent power transients from damaging your speakers.

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that whatever other speakers are added, pushing potentially 900 watts through the original 150 watt speakers will probably wreck them?

Comment: @Tim Thanks, you right, but I was just wondering if its possible cheers :)

Comment: It is feasible, but if it was my gear, I'd make sure it never went above a quarter power on the amp. And, I'd be looking for some replacement speakers or a big power sink.

Answer (score 0):

The Peavey PV 2600 Power Amp is 2 x 900W RMS @ 4 ohms, 540W RMS @ 8 ohms, or 1800W RMS bridged mono.  What is your amp config?

The speaker combination in watts must be greater than amp output

Comment: Hey Peter Thanks, 

I have 4 150W Speakers rated @ 4-8 ohms.

Comment: Unless you keep your amp low, you're going to charcoal these speakers